# JavaScript writing event driven callbacks

Tags: javascript, function, object, callback

I'm writing a sort of library that will pass various events coming from the server, do some processing and pass the result into the client side JavaScript. I've seen socket.io having events like `socket.on("message", callback()}`. I have a place where I need to get the message from server and pass it to the frontend like `myobj.on("message",callback())` and there is another scenario where I need to play an audio and then when the audio ends I need to fire the same `on` function with a different event and callback. Like `myobj.on("audioEnded", callback())`.

I'm having the audio playback function like this:

```
var self = this;

this.socket.on("audio", function (audio) {
    audio = JSON.parse(audio);
    var audioUrl =
      "data:audio/ogg;base64," + audio.data;
    self.audioElem = new Audio();
    self.audioElem.src = audioUrl;
    self.audioElem.play();
    self.audioElem.onended = (I want to notify the on function of the frontend JavaScript from here.)
  });
```

How do I write this `on` function for notifying events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `subscribe' function

```
const Subscriptions = {}
function subscribe (type, callback) {  
    const current = Subscriptions[type]
    if (current) {
        current.push(callback)
    } else {
        Subscriptions[type] = [callback]
    }
}
function send (action, value) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ action, value }))  
}
ws.onmessage = evt => {     // ws -> websocket
    const info = JSON.parse(evt.data)    
    const { action, content } = info

    const handlers = Subscriptions[action]
    handlers && handlers.forEach(callback => callback(content, info))
}
// And all your socket messages should look like this:

//send(':login', { phone: '15089320000', password: 'xxxxx' })
subscribe(':login', (content, info) => ...)
{
    action: ":login"
    content: {state: 1, aid: 1, name: "Super Can", info: {name: "Super Can", level: "Super Level!"},…}
}
```

Then your codes should be looked like:

```
subscribe('audio', audio => {   // audio is already a JSON, no need to parse again
    const audioUrl =
      "data:audio/ogg;base64," + audio.data;
    self.audioElem = new Audio();
     ....
})
```

**BUT I am not using socket.io, using WebSocket instead.**

[image]